# Extending namespaced module from within

Tags: javascript, oop, this, module-pattern

**Code:**

```
;(function (ns, undefined) {
  ns = {
    foo1: "bar1"
  }

  this.ns = {
    foo2: "bar2"
  };

  ns.foo3 = "bar3";

  return ns;

})(window.ns = window.ns || {});
```

**Results:**

Calling `ns` result: `Object {foo2: "bar2"}`

IIFE returns: `Object {foo: "bar1", foo3: "bar3"}`

**1. Do I understand it correctly?**

- `ns` is a new, private object inside IIFE which is then returned
- `this.ns` belongs to `window.ns` and expands it

**2. Why `this` keyword in `this.ns`?**

Since IIFE is invoked in global context, `this` keyword is linked
with global, hence: `document.ns` (the namespace)

**3. How to properly access `this.ns` properties inside IIFE?**

e.g `console.log(this.ns.foo2)` - is it the proper way?

**4. Since I passed `window.ns` as `ns` argument, why would I have to use `this.ns` and not just `ns` only?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What argument is IIFE called with?

The window object does not have an `.ns` property on it at runtime. Therefore `window.ns` will evaluate to `undefined`, which in a `||` expression will coerce to `false` while `{}` will coerce to `true`. The `||` expression will therefore end up being `false || true` resulting in `window.ns = {}` being passed as the argument to the IIFE.

### What happens inside the IIFE?

The `ns` parameter is passed the `window.ns = {}` argument and then `ns = {foo1: 'bar1'}` assigns a new value to `ns` and next the `ns.foo3 = 'bar3` adds another property/value pair to it.

The `this` defaults to the global object (window object in the browser) when it is used in a function declared in the global scope. The `this.ns = {foo2: 'bar2'}` therefore creates a new property on the window object with the name `.ns` and the value `{foo2: 'bar2'}`.

### How to access `window.ns` and `ns`?

You can access `window.ns` from everywhere since it belongs to the global scope.

It is only the IIFE and functions within it that can access `ns` since it is declared in the lexical scope of the IIFE. However since the IIFE returns `ns`, it is possible to store the return value in a variable in the global scope and thereby make `ns` accessible outside the lexical scope of the IIFE.

Comment: Inside IIFE if I declare `ns = { foo: "bar" }`, then type `ns` in console - I don't get that declared object. **BUT** when I declare `ns.foo = "bar"` and type `ns` in console, I get that object. So, I can extend passed `{}` as `ns` only with dot notation?

Comment: The only `ns` you can access outside the IIFE is the one which is a property on the global object. The `ns` parameter inside IIFE can only be accessed by IIFE and any function inside IIFE. Using dot notation does not change that. So if typing `ns` in the console returns something it is because there is an `.ns` property on the global object.

Comment: There's a difference.  If I declare `ns = { ... }` first, and then add properties, typing `ns` in console shows nothing. But If I add properties first using dot notation, the properties are being added to the passed `{}` object. As I understand this behaviour: `literal obj. notation` overwrites passed `ns` but by using `dot notation` I **access** the passed `ns` and then add property to it. Is that right? Is it possible to use `literal notation` that would extend passed `ns` object?

Comment: *Literal obj. notation overwrites passed ns* --> correct. *Using dot notation I access the passed ns and then add property to it* --> also correct. *Is it possible to use literal notation that would extend passed ns object* --> no.